# How to get innerHTML including data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm using `document.body.innerHTML` to get a text version of the HTML so I can store it and reload it later using jQuery's `append`. It works fine but it isn't saving the `data-*` attributes that I'm storing in the HTML nodes. Is there a method that can get me a string of all the innerHTML including this data attributes?

Comment: I think you are saving data attribute using `data()` method instead that use `attr()`

Comment: Mind the difference between Javascript element properties and HTML attributes. If you set a Javascript property (e.g. using `.val()` or `.data()` etc) you are not changing the respective HTML attributes

Comment: you can clone the innerHTML using a `deep copy` to copy the HTML along with data attributes.

Comment: @PranavCBalan That was exactly the problem. I was setting the data attributes using data(). Thank you!

Comment: @Phob1a : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery `.data()`:

jQuery's `.data()` method is storing data in Javascript and not as HTML attributes. Only existing `data-*` attributes are pulled into that object. For more information [check the docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

To save the data as HTML data attributes use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). Something like the following:

```
$('.el').attr('data-foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .clone() to clone html using jQuery

Sample html:

```
<div class="divSource" data-test="Hello" data-test2="World">
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Div" />

<div id="divDesti">   
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnClone").click(function() {
    var colnedSource = $(".divSource:first").clone();

    $("#divDesti").append(colnedSource);
  });
});
```

Output after 3 clones:

[image]